# How to obtain "stacking grid" in Susy (column on top of another)

Tags: css, sass, susy-compass

Being completely new to susy and responsive web design, I'm trying to understand how to obtain this result with Susy (grid framework I've chosen): http://semantic.gs/examples/responsive/responsive.html

I can't find a way to achieve the same result so I started asking myself if Susy is intended to **avoid** that way of handling a layout grid.

I would like to know if it's possible to obtain that result (and how) or, otherwise, if Susy is not intended for that type of grid.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Susy is designed to let you decide how your grids work, and how they change. What you want is a simple mobile-first layout pattern - very easy with Susy. The stacking part is automatic: block elements stack by default - you don't even need Susy. You only need Susy above a given breakpoint. For that, you can use `at-breakpoint`:

```
// your small screen layout

@include at-breakpoint($total-columns) {
  // your large-screen layout
}
```

Check the [Susy Docs](http://susy.oddbird.net/guides/reference/) for more details on what all you can do. There's even [a demo](http://susy.oddbird.net/demos/magic/) for this.

Comment: That's nice, I didn't get that the demo is the page itself 'till you pointed that out. I thought they forgot the link or something similar